# catkin_make fails - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: catkin-make, make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i am struggling the last few days and tried many things out which i've found on the web. My problem is to build with catkin_make. I am quite new to all this stuff and have absolutely no clue what to do. Would be very happy if anybody can help me.

i get following error

---

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"dircol<Dimensions<10ul, 3ul> >::setFinalState(Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 1, 0, 10, 1>)", referenced from:
  _main in dircol_rezero_ipopt.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [/Users/lukasmoller/catkin_ws/devel/lib/dircol/dircol_rezero_ipopt] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/dircol_rezero_ipopt.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/dircol_rezero_ipopt.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [dircol_rezero_ipopt] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

Thanks very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196953/catkin_make-fails----undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86_64/) by [Rufio](https://answers.ros.org/users/20729/rufio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2014-11-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-10**:
Please do not use answers to make comments, either comment on my answer or edit your question.

**Comment by [kunalgrover05](https://answers.ros.org/users/23779/kunalgrover05/) on 2015-09-06**:
Were you able to solve this issue? Stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @Rufio, this is more of a C++ question than a `catkin_make` question. The error you are getting:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"dircol<Dimensions<10ul, 3ul> >::setFinalState(Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 1, 0, 10, 1>)", referenced from:
  _main in dircol_rezero_ipopt.cpp.o
```

Is from the C++ linker. It is complaining that it cannot find the `_main` symbol which means you are trying to build an executable but you do not have a main function in any of your source files you are compiling and linking together for the executable.

Check your program to make sure it has a `main` function and if it does, make sure the file which contains it is used in compiling your executable.

If you need more help we will need you to share your `CMakeLists.txt` and possibly some of the source files. The easiest way to get help would be to post your whole package on Github.com and point people there (assuming you can do that).

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-10**:
(moved from answer) "It is very strange: when i do "catkin_make" with ubuntu on my virtual machine, it works without any error :). So it must be anything with my system. Unfortunately it is a project from my university and i most probably are not allowed to share any files :(."

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-10**:
(moved from answer) "Could it be that it is an error which arise only for mac osx (10.10)?"

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-10**:
@Rufio Not that I know of, you should try to narrow down the problem, removing everything until you can reproduce it without any of your projects code. If you can do that and still have the problem then you can post the minimal project which exposes it and we can help using that as an example.